# Is there any way to list the accessible BigQuery dataset in other projects?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm granted to access some bigquery datasets in other people's project. Some of them are only view permission, while others are not.
I'd like to list up the datasets accessible from my google account (not only the datasets under my project) and the permission I have for each dataset. I'm searching documents but I couldn't find how to do that.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls

Do you know the good way? It's better if I can do that from console.